# Check if values in checked row are equivalent

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My application allows you to track orders in a store database. This database contains a weak entity used for `notes` which is attached to an `orderID`. I want to allow users to be able to apply to same 'note' to many orders at the same time, but there are some fields in the `notes` table that are dependent on the `location` of the sale. In other words, you should only be allowed to apply the same note if all the sale locations are the same.

Simplified View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Note", FormMethod.Get, new { name = "editForm" }))
{
    <table id="DataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="checkboxValidation()"/>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.location)
            </th>
        </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
    <tr >
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="@item.orderID" />
        </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(item.OrderID.ToString(), "Details", "Search", new { orderID = item.orderID.ToString() }, null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.location)
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

`checkboxValidation()` is a javascript function I wrote to check if at least 1 checkbox is checked. How would I add a check to make sure all of the locations on checked lines are the same? Is this even possible? Thanks

EDIT: I missed a detail. When clicking the edit button, if the check is successful, it submits the form, which brings up the `notes` editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly straightforward using JQuery:

```
// find all the checked rows
var checkedItems = $("#DataTable").find("tr td input[type=checkbox]");

// construct a locations array for all checked items
var locations = [];
checkedItems.each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).is(":checked")) {
        locations.push($(this).closest("td").next("td").next("td").text().trim());
    }
});

// confirm each location is the same
var valid = true;
locations.each(function(index, element) {
    if (index > 0 && locations[index-1] != element) {
        valid = false;
        return;
    }
});
```

One additional thing you might want to do, is add some data tags to your `tr` and `td` elements, so that you can write more robust selectors that won't break with a minor UI re-arrangement (like `tr[data-role=check]` and `tr[data-role=location]`, etc).

---

(Using [JQuery closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and and [JQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).)

Comment: Seems like a simple solution. I'm no master in JS, so perhaps you could entertain me by explaining a couple things? I have having issues understanding `push`, `closest`, and `function(i, e)`. I assume push is just adding that item to `locations`. What exactly determines how 'close' an element is to another? Thanks

Comment: @Jeff yes, `push` adds an item to an array.  `Closest` gets the first element that matches the selector, going up the DOM tree (ie, I used it here just to get the `td` element belonging to the checkbox).  `function(i, e)` is the iterator function for `each` - you could name `i` and `e` anything of course, but they're the index of the current item, and the item itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seems that Visual studio does not like this line `if (element.is(":checked")) {`. The error message given is `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`. When debugging, the issue seems to be with `.is`. I am using JS 1.8.0

Comment: @Jeff ah right ... I suppose it needs to be wrapped in a JQuery object -- use `$(element).is ...`

Comment: I had actually just figured that out as you posted the correction. Got the same error down below and fixed by doing this `$(locations).each`. Why is it required here, but not above with `checkedItems.each`?

Comment: @Jeff oh, right.  `checkedItems` is already a JQuery object, so it has the `each` method attached to it.  `locations` is a plain Javascript array.